# In Spring boot and thymeleaf dropdown select option, I have = the server responded with a status of 404 () thymeleaf select option + oneTomany form

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and stuck with this error :404 when I save the new record of the table "Pret" (add). In the class form, I can selecte the title of the "Livre" and the name of the "Lecteur". And then my addPret.html is desinged as.

```
<form th:action="@{SavePret}" method="post" 
             th:object="${pretFormulaire}">
     <select th:field="*{livre}">
          <option th:each="livre:${listLivres}"
                        th:value="${livre}"
                        th:text="${livre.titre}">   
          </option>
     </select> 
     <select th:field="*{lecteur}">
        <option th:each="lecteur:${listLecteurs}" 
                 th:value="${lecteur}" th:text="${lecteur.nom}">  
        </option>
    </select>
   <button type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

And here the controller first method signature :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String formPret(Model model) {
    Pret pretFormulaire=new Pret();
    model.addAttribute("pretFormulaire", pretFormulaire);
    List<Lecteur> listLecteurs=lecteurRepository.findAll();
    List<Livre> listLivres=livreRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("listLecteurs", listLecteurs);
    model.addAttribute("listLivres", listLivres);
    return "Form";
}
```

The controller method of savePret is like this :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/savePret")
    public String savePret2(@Valid @ModelAttribute("pret") 
              Pret pret, BindingResult bindingResult, 
               Long livre_id, Long lecteur_id){

        Livre livre=livreRepository.findOne(livre_id);
        Lecteur lecteur=lecteurRepository.findOne(lecteur_id);
        livre.setNbFoisPret(livre.getNbFoisPret()+1);
        livre.setDisponible(livre.getDisponible()+"Non");
        pret.setLecteur(lecteur);
        pret.setLivre(livre);
        pret.setDatePret(new Date());
        pretRepository.save(pret);

        return "redirect:Index";
    }
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form th:action="@{SavePret}" method="post"
```

should be

```
<form th:action="@{/savePret}" method="post"
```

Comment: Thank you! but I still have  = [There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).]

Comment: Is there anyone who would like to help me please!

Comment: your view resolver has to resolve view named "Index" because you returned "redirect:Index"; check @RequestMapping("/Index") or typo.

Comment: the problem is that "select option" returns under type "String" instead of type "Object". How can this conversion be promoted? Thanks !